# Identify and append prefix to strings in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a column  `description` where the data is stored as `Hello I’m new to this organisation please guide`

My output should be - `Hello I’m new to this marketing organisation please guide`

I need to append marketing before organisation

Comment: `replace(description, 'organisation', 'marketing organisation')`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "organization" only appears once -- or if all occurrences should be replaced -- then the simplest method is `replace()`:

```
select replace(col, 'organization', 'marketing organization')
```

If "organization" could appear more than once, then you can use `regexp_replace()`, which lets you better control *which* "organization" is replaced.  However, your question suggests that "organization" only appears once.

Comment: Thanks . That’s what I was looking out for .